# Grails Domain Comparator

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a String field named as `versionNumber` that contains a version number with this String style: `integer.integer.integer p.e. 4.4.4`

I have an HQL query for retrieving the max value of this field:

`Class.executeQuery('select max(versionNumber) from Class')`

With that query I don't get a correct value, I get `4.4.1 > 4.21.3`

How can I create a comparator for this column?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: I use mysql @Ivar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is to split the versionNumber into tokens and order those tokens:

```
Class.executeQuery(‘SELECT versionNumber FROM Class
                ORDER BY 
                CAST(SUBSTRING(versionNumber, 1, LOCATE(‘.’, versionNumber) - 1) AS INTEGER),
                CAST(SUBSTRING(versionNumber, LOCATE(‘.’, versionNumber) + 1, locate('.', versionNumber, locate('.', versionNumber) + 1) - locate('.', versionNumber) - 1) AS INTEGER
                CAST(SUBSTRING(versionNumber, LOCATE('.', versionNumber, LOCATE(‘.’, versionNumber) + 1) + 1, LOCATE('.', versionNumber, LOCATE('.', versionNumber, LOCATE('.', versionNumber) + 1) + 1) - LOCATE('.', versionNumber, LOCATE('.', versionNumber) +  1) - 1) AS INTEGER)
            ‘), [max: 1])
```

It looks a bit ugly, but does it job in optimal way.

Comment: Prefer this once over my answer. (also because it is not dbms dependent) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a formula to divide the version parts. Then you can order by those versions and get the top result.

```
class DomainWithVersion {
    String version;

    Integer versionMajor;
    Integer versionMinor;
    Integer versionBuild;

    static mapping = {
        // SUBSTRING_INDEX is a MySQL function
        versionMajor(formula: 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 1)')
        versionMinor(formula: 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 2), '.', -1)')
        versionBuild(formula: 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -1)')
    }
}
```

```
DomainWithVersion.executeQuery('select versionNumber from DomainWithVersion dwv order by dwv.versionMajor, dwv.versionMinor, dwv.versionBuild', [], [max: 1])
```